# Why is SUBSTRING(DateUpdated,0,11) different than the first 11 characters of DateUpdated?

Tags: sql, datetime, timezone, intersystems-cache

I'm assuming this is some sort of timezone offset issue, but can anyone explain exactly what is happening here?  Note that this is [intersystems-cache](/questions/tagged/intersystems-cache).

```
SELECT 
    DateUpdated,
    TimeUpdated, 
    SUBSTRING(dateUpdated,0,11) as DU, 
    SUBSTRING(timeUpdated,0,11) as TU
FROM Schema.Table
```

[image]

Why is `SUBSTRING(DateUpdated,0,11)` different than the first 11 characters of `DateUpdated`?

Comment: What is the datatype of dateUpdated and timeUpdated ?

Comment: Both are `DATA_TYPE: 93`, `TYPE_NAME: TIMESTAMP` and `SQL_DATA_TYPE: 11`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would be better if you will past definition in this class for this properties. And anyway I would not recommend to work with dates as with strings. Instead you should use [CONVERT](http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RSQL_convert) function, where `CONVERT(Date, DateUpdated)` returns only date, and `CONVERT(Time, DateUpdated)` only time from this property

Comment: "And anyway I would recommend to work with dates as with strings". I think you mean "I would NOT recommend".